# What is the "pythonic" way to slicing list of lines from a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists `start_list` and `end_list`. I need to strip the lines starting from the line numbers in the `start_list` and ending with the corresponding line number in the `end_list`. And then need to write these into another file. What is the most "pythonic" way to do it?

I tried it with using two `for` loops way in C++. I would like to know about the most efficient way in python to do this. I tried to use `islice()` function inside the loop, but it is not giving the correct result. Please check the below code for my implementation.

```
content = []    
try:
    with open(dir+ '/' + file_name, "r") as file: 
        for start, end in zip(start_list, end_list):
            for lines in itertools.islice(file, start, end):
                content.append(lines)
```

Comment: _What is the most "pythonic" way to do this?_ Generally the most "pythonic" way of building a list with for loops is to make use of [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: from documentation: "If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use list(f) or f.readlines()". then you can 'islice' that list. If your file is very big then maybe use a counter in your for loop and check when you start and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use islice with file object this way. Once the lines are read, you cannot go backward into the file without explicitly asking for it.

Either you add a `file.seek(0)` before your second `for`

Or you read the file once, and you iterate on the file content in memory:

```
content = []
try:
    with open(os.path.join(dir, file_name), "r") as file:
        file_content = file.readlines()

    for start, end in zip(start_list, end_list):
        content.extend(file_content[start:end])
```

Comment: better use os.path.join(). Note dir is a reserved word

Comment: @joaquin you are right. I did not change the initial code.

Answer (score 1):

try this once with linecache util-

```
import linecache
content=[]
file_path="path_to_file"
for start, end in zip(start_list, end_list):
    for line_no in range(start,end):
        content.append(linecache.getline(file_path,line_no))
```

be aware that

> This function will never raise an exception — it will return '' on
>   errors (the terminating newline character will be included for lines
>   that are found).

more details at https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html